# Cómo obtener la URL y un parámetro del form en el controlador con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-8, laravel-7

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema con laravel y blade pero me tope con un detalle. Al querer recoger el ID de la ruta que hace el llamado al controlador al que he enviado.

Es decir tengo una ruta http://127.0.0.1:8000/deportes/playera/27  y aquí tengo un formulario que me envía a un controlador donde necesito recoger el  id o parametro 27 para el caso anterior.

Hasta ahorita lo que he hecho es agregar un input hidden en el formulario con el valor del id, como muestro a continuación:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_playera" id="id_platera value="{{ request()->route()->parameters['id'] }} " >
```

De esa forma he logrado recoger el id dentro de mi controlador pero me gustaría saber si existe una forma directa en que pueda tomar ese id de la ruta que llama a mi controlador directamente para un código más limpio.

Comment: metelo como parametro en la ruta del formulario

Answer (score 0):

Debes preparar tu ruta para recibir ese id y ademas los datos por post
En la ruta de tu formulario por el parametro

```
<form method="PUT" action="{{ route('playera.update',$request()->route()->parameters['model_id']) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

en las rutas debes tenerla asi

```
Route::put('playera/update', 'PlayeraController@update');
```

tu controlador

```
public function update(Request $request, $model_id)
{
}
```

Ya en tu funcion update ademas del formulario te llega el id

Comment: El atributo method de un form solo acepta get o post, en caso de requerise algún otro verbo se debería hacer mediante la directiva que blade ofrece para ello. Se puede consultar mas al respecto aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field

Comment: Entiendo, lo que busco es tomar directamente el id en el controlador sin necesidad de enviarlo en el action o como un input del form. Suponía que tal vez podría existir una forma de obtener la ruta que esta haciendo la petición directamente en el controlador y de ahí obtener el parámetro.

Comment: el Id debe viajar con el cliente

Comment: @CristianCamilo Además de lo que te dicen de los verbos, ten en cuenta que debes declarar el parámetro en la ruta, o sea `Route::put('/playera/{id}', [PlayeraController::class, 'update']);');` pues ese {id}, es el parámetro $model_id que toma como argumento la función del controlador